# Unable to setup git with jailed user

Tags: linux, debian, git, chroot

I have performed below steps to setup jailed user 
here username is test3

```
mkdir -p /home/test3/{dev,etc,lib,usr,bin}
mkdir -p /home/test3/usr/bin
chown root.test3 /home/test3
mknod -m 666 /home/test3/dev/null c 1 3
cd /home/test3/etc
cp /etc/ld.so.cache .
cp /etc/ld.so.conf .
cp /etc/nsswitch.conf .
cp /etc/hosts .
cd /home/test/usr/bin
cp /bin/ls .
cp /bin/bash .
cd /sbin
wget -O l2chroot http://www.cyberciti.biz/files/lighttpd/l2chroot.txt
chmod +x l2chroot
```

edit the `l2chroot` file and change `BASE=”/webroot”` to `BASE=”/home/test”`. This tells `l2chroot` where your jail is located so it copies everything to the right place. Now go ahead and run the command on the binaries you want.

```
l2chroot /bin/ls
l2chroot /bin/bash
l2chroot /usr/bin/git*
```

mounted test.git to /home/test3/home/test3.git

```
mount --bind /path/test.git /home/test3/home/test3.git
```

created a new group and added test3 user into it 
changed the group of test.git to git

edited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
Match User test3
         ChrootDirectory /home/test3/
         X11Forwarding no
         AllowTcpForwarding no
         PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Able to do ssh to test3

But while doing `git clone ssh://domain.com:22/home/test3/home/test3.git`

```
**Error : fatal: '/home/test3/home/test.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**
```

Comment: The error notification tells about `test.git` repository while you mentioned `test3.git`. Which one is right?

Answer (score 4):

Since you have jailed the user, `/home/test3` will become a root directory for logged in user. To access it you should specify the path correctly, either absolute or relative:

```
git clone domain.com:/home/test3.git
```

Comment: Excellent It worked for me